# Brushed DC Motor with BTN8962TA

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I'd like some feedback on a high current, bi-directional motor controller I'm building using 2 BTN8962TA chips. To control it, I use a 3.3v microcontroller. To start the motor, I raise `ON` to `HIGH` and use PWM on either `FOREWARD_MOTOR` or `BACKWARD_MOTOR` nets to control the motor speed.

Have I missed anything here? Is some sort of flyback protection needed (TVS or otherwise) to protect the 12V rail for other components?

I'm also having trouble with measuring the current using the `IS` pins on the BTN8962TA. I'm guessing it has to do with using PWM to control the speed. Also, I'm betting the 510Ω current sense resistor is incorrect for the 3.3v microcontroller.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Infineon publishes a datasheet and applications information for this device. Have you referred to these?

Comment: I have looked over the data sheet, but I’m far from an expert here. Was hoping for some validation from the community on the approach.